# Different result for same query on maria DB server version 10 and mysqli driver

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am struggling with strange situation where data on both palaces is same but my server has mariadb server version 10.* while my development server has mysql version 5.*

Here is the query which is not working correctly

```
SELECT
    t.sponsor_id,
    @user_id
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, sponsor_id
    FROM profiles
    ORDER BY user_id DESC
) AS t ,
(select @user_id := 101 ) initialize
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.user_id, @user_id) > 0 AND
      @user_id := concat(@user_id, ',', t.sponsor_id)
```

The same query produces different result set

Here is the output of development server

[image: Output of development serve]

Output of Production server is

```
   sponsor_id  | @user_id
   -----------------------
   101         |  101, 100
```

Please help me out of this

Comment: Just a suggestion, but could the initialization of the session variables have something to do with this?

Comment: Actually i don't know what could be the reason i am open to any modification

Comment: Which exactly is your MySql version 5.?

Comment: I ask because a while ago I went through a similar problem that I asked on the Database Administrators, read it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117449/really-strange-behavior-using-variables-in-mysql-query)

Comment: Are they different versions?  Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the logic to avoid setting and reading `@user_id` within the same query. Both [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/user-defined-variables/) explicitly warn about such queries being non-deterministic.

MySQL:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement.  <...> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get
>   the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

MariaDB:

> It is unsafe to read a user-defined variable and set its value in the
>   same statement (unless the command is SET), because the order of these
>   actions is undefined.

*Note: If you are tempted to say "but it has always worked for me before", please read again. It **might** work, but it is not guaranteed.*

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate all @variables.  Focus on `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Without knowing what the data, the schema, or the desired output is, I can only guess that something like this might work:

```
SELECT  sponsor_id
        GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id) AS users
    FROM profiles
    ORDER BY sponsor_id;
```